# Is there a way to print to a preset location for print-to-file?

Tags: linux, printing

I would like to add a "printer" under Linux that would automatically print-to-file to a specific folder and default to PDF. The idea being that I could one-click-print documents for printing later in the day when I had access to a printer. File names don't matter in this case.

Is this possible to do? I am willing to write some code to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you are using `cups`. You usually need separate package `cups-pdf`. You can then setup a virtual PDF printer in CUPS admin (`http://localhost:631`) which will place PDF files in `/var/spool/cups-pdf/<USER>`

Comment: This is what I wanted. Except for me under Linux Mint the directory was /home/<USER>/PDF